# .net core 2.2 webapi and handling multypart request

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .net core 2.2 webapi as backend.
My backend have to handling the requests *(photo and text)* from mobile application  as **multypart-form** request.
Plz hint me how it to prpvide on backend?

Comment: There are a ton of examples out there.  A Google search for "net core 2.2 webapi multipart/form-data" yielded a bunch of step by step tutorials (such as https://dottutorials.net/dotnet-core-web-api-multipart-form-data-upload-file/)  I would start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem has solved

```
    public class SwaggerFileOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.OperationId == "MailWithPhotos")
        {
            operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>
            {
                new NonBodyParameter
                {
                    Name = "awr_file",
                    Required = false,
                    Type = "file",
                    In = "formData"
                },
                new  NonBodyParameter
                {
                    Name = "awr_message",
                    Required = true,
                    Type = "string",
                    In = "formData"
                },
                new  NonBodyParameter
                {
                    Type = "string",
                    In = "header",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Description = "token",
                    Required = true

                }
            };
        }
    }
}

    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseMail), 200)]
    public async Task<PipeResponse> MailWithPhotos([FromForm] MailwithPhoto fIleUploadAPI)
    {

        var file = fIleUploadAPI.awr_file;                     // OK!!!
        var message = fIleUploadAPI.awr_message;          // OK!!!
        var tokenA = Request.Headers["Authorization"];    // OK!!!

        var fileContentStream11 = new MemoryStream();

        await fIleUploadAPI.awr_file.CopyToAsync(fileContentStream11);
        await System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(Path.Combine(folderPath,
                                        fIleUploadAPI.awr_file.FileName),
                                        fileContentStream11.ToArray());
```

}

```
    public class MailwithPhoto
    {
        public string awr_message { get; set; } 
        public string Authorization { get; set; } 
        public IFormFile awr_file { get; set; }
    }
```